# Does awaiting for Task.Run always wait for response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm trying to implement an await Task.Run in my controller and then return the response.

Just curious if the response will always be got before we attempt to return it.

```
            var response = await Task.Run(() => _myService.GetResponse(refno));
            return Ok(response);
```

Could it attempt to return a response which hasn't been set yet?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this construct in stead of just doing ```var response = _myService.GetResponse(refno);```? Returning the response before it was set could only happen if your ```_myService.GetResponse``` method is async since you're not awaiting that specific call. Is there an error scenario in which the service returns null? Or throws an exception? Because that would leave you with an unset ```response```.

Comment: Just change the signature of your controller method to return void without async when you aren't calling another async method. Asp.net also supports this signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task.Run will immediately return an unfinished task. With the await you are waiting for the task to complete without blocking your thread. The task will only complete, when `_myService.GetResponse(refno))` returns or throws a exception.

In short:
Your response will always been set, when you hit your second line. But `_myService.GetResponse(refno)` could throw an exception. In this case the exception will be rethrown and you will not reach your second line.

Answer (score 3):

```
var response = await Task.Run(() => _myService.GetResponse(refno));
return Ok(response);
```

> Could it attempt to return a response which hasn't been set yet?

No; as you can see from the code, `response` is assigned to before it is returned. In fact, C# won't let you use unassigned variables; that's part of its type safety.

However, **you should never do this!** [There's no benefit to doing `await Task.Run` on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

If you can change `GetResponse` to be asynchronous, then do that:

```
var response = await _myService.GetResponseAsync(refno);
return Ok(response);
```

Otherwise, just call it synchronously:

```
var response = _myService.GetResponse(refno);
return Ok(response);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Stephen. I decided not to use async and I'm just going synchronously.  Funnily, I had just been reading some of your blogs. Good stuff!